# Writing text files with node webkit

Tags: node.js, file, text, node-webkit

I'm trying to do something rather simple: write a text file with data entered in a text input field to a file...

```
var data = document.getElementById("fileContent").value;
fs.writeFileSync("test.txt", data);
```

For instance if I type in,

```
Write this to file 123 123
```

I end up with this in the file...

```
Write this to
```

If I hard code a string into the application, it writes correctly.

```
fs.writeFileSync("test.txt", "this is a hard coded string");
```

I tried using writeFileSync with and without the encoding parameter set. I've tried createWriteStream with and without encoding the parameter set. I've tried fileOpen, fs.writeSync, and fs.close. I even tried converting the  date to a Buffer object and writing that. In every case, I got the exact same results.

The encoding is also strange. Notepad++ indicates that the encoding is "UCS2-LE w/o BOM" I'd expect it to be UTF-8, as I'v been setting the encoding parameter to that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Okay... here does appear to be a difference in the encoding between text data and hard-coded strings. Here are the byte representations of each of the scenarios for the string "Hello World".


`
//values from the text box
0: 72
1: 0
2: 101
3: 0
4: 108
5: 0
6: 108
7: 0
8: 111
9: 0
10: 119
11: 0

//Hard coded values
0: 72
1: 101
2: 108
3: 108
4: 111
5: 32
6: 87
7: 111
8: 114
9: 108
10: 100
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's a bug with Node-Webkit-v0.9.*
2. It's OK if you use Node-Webkit-v.8.* or lower version.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research and determining it was something with encoding, I stumbled on this post. Apparently, utf8 doesn't work...

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/node-webkit/3M-0v92o9Zs/eSYnSZ8dUK0J

I changed the encoding it to  "utf16le", and this appears to write the text correctly for hard-coded text and text from a text box.