# Mongoose inserting \u0000

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-webkit

I'm having trouble inserting text in mongoDb from an html input in node-webkit.

I have this html bad boy here :

```
<input id="cats" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

I am using mongoose to save this :

```
function saveACat(){
   var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: $("#cats").val() });
   fluffy.save(function(err,fluffy){
       if (err) return console.error(err);
   });
}
```

When i enter Hello in the "cats" field the inserted data is : H\u0000e\u0000l\u0000l\u0000l\o0000

When i hardcode the text instead of taking it from "cats" field the insert work correctly.

Any idea ?

Comment: It looks like it's not UTF-8 encoded. I'm not sure how/why you're using jQuery on the server?

Comment: This is in node-webkit its basically a web app for desktop so the user enter a value in "cats" so I figured out that the easiest way to access the data in the field was to use jquery instead of javascript. I will try the UTF-8 encoding thanks.

Comment: I tried to set the whole Html document containing the input in UTF-8 it didn't work and I also tried adding a meta tag to set the charset to UTF-8 it didn't work either any others idea ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with node-webkit, but it might be a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290362/writing-text-files-with-node-webkit (while it's not the identical problem you're having, it's similar in nature that utf8 encoding doesn't seem to work).

Comment: Oh      my       god   .... thank you so much for this link it seem you were right its a bug in node-webkit v0.9 I reverted to v0.8.6 and its all fine now thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like WiredPrairie said it seem to be a bug in node webkit v0.9.2 I simply reverted to v0.8.6 and its now working I can correctly insert non-hardcoded text in mongoDB.

Here's the link that made me realise the problem [stackoverflow.com/questions/23290362/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290362/)